# Trying to call async method - await vs GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to write a class with a method that will get some data from a REST API (the googleapi for youtube playlists) and dump that data into an ObservableCollection. The problem I am encountering is that when I call this:

```
this.getPlaylistItemsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

the code executes.

When I call this:

```
await this.getPlaylistItemsAsync();
```

it simply skips over the code.

I am pretty new to the whole asynchrounous programming thingy... I thikn I understand the basic concepts.. I just can't figure out how to do it :(

The full code is here:

```
#define DEBUG
//#define TestEnvi

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



namespace IntuifaceYTPlaylist {

public class IFYT_Playlist {
    
    public string playlistID {get;set;}= "PLYu7z3I8tdEmpjIoZHybXD4xmXXYrTqlk";  // The ID with which we identify our playlist
    private string key = "supersecretAPIkey";    // The API-Key we use to access the google-API
    public ObservableCollection<string> videosList {get;set;}= new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public IFYT_Playlist () {
        Console.WriteLine("Class Loaded!");
#if TestEnvi
        this.getPlaylistItemsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine("This worked!");
        await this.getPlaylistItemsAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("This didn't!"); //In fact this line isn't even executed :(
#endif
    }

#region getData

    public async void update (){
        this.getPlaylistItemsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    // Access the REST-API to retrieve the full dataset
    // TODO: Manage connection to the API - DONE
    // TODO: Parse JSON
    public async Task<ObservableCollection<string>> getPlaylistItemsAsync(){

        var output = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        string URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string query = URL + "?key=" + this.key + "&part=contentDetails&playlistId=" + this.playlistID + "&maxResults=50";

        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(query);  //Dump the JSON string into an object!

# if DEBUG
        // Dump the response into a file - just so we can check it if something goes wrong...
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine("", "Dump.json")))
        {
                outputFile.WriteLine(response);
        }
#endif

        var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);

        // Iterate over the items in the list to get the VideoIDs of the individual videos
        foreach (var item in responseData.items){
            output.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item.contentDetails.videoId));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);

#if DEBUG   //Let's see if that worked....
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Printing VideoIDs:");
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var item in output){
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
#endif


    this.videosList = output;
    return output;    
    }
#endregion
}

}
```

The program I use to call this looks like this:

```
using System;
using IntuifaceYTPlaylist;

namespace TestEnvi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            Create();
        }

        static async void Create(){
            IFYT_Playlist playlist = new IFYT_Playlist();
            playlist.getPlaylistItemsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("This worked!");
            await playlist.getPlaylistItemsAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Did this?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "skips over the code" here in your case? I don't even see where you're trying to fill the collection with the results.

Comment: `async void` is the main problem here. That's "fire and forget". As soon as you reach an `await` inside it that's not already satisfied, it returns.

Comment: How does this even compile? You are calling `await` in a constructor.

Comment: it does not excetue the code but instead cancels out of the program without throwing any messages.

Comment: `public async void update ()` is a *huge* red flag; you should almost never have an `async void` method - try making that `public async Task UpdateAsync()` and await if from the caller?

Comment: How do you inspect the results?

Answer (score 2):

Invoked method immediately returns to the caller (i.e. to the `Main`) on first `await` and from there, both (the caller and the invoked method) run concurrently. Yet, since the `Main` finishes first, the whole program ends.

Thus, if you want to wait for asynchronous call completion you may change `Create()` to return `Task` rather than `void` and then you can wait such as:  `Create().Wait();`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your code example, where exactly you're trying to update the list, because the code which you are pointing out to can't even be compiled. You can't use the `await` keyword in constructors, because constructors can't be `async`.

The main reason why you don't see console output is because your `Main` method doesn't wait for your `async void Create` to finish, because `Create` is async operation and as we know it's non blocking. Therefore your main thread just triggers the `Create` operation and continue doing other stuff below. But there is nothing below and that's it, the program is done.

To fix it, you should either turn your `Main` method to `async` method and call `await Create()`, or just call `Create().Wait`. You can also call `Console.ReadLine` if this is the console application.

By the way, it works with `this.getPlaylistItemsAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, because it's not asynchronous code any more, your `Create`  method is blocked and it waits for the `getPlaylistItemsAsync` to finish. Similarly your `Main` method also waits for the `Create` to return, so that the program keep working.

You also have `async void update` method which you probably use somewhere (I don't know), so be careful with it since you don't have a way to know whether the method has finish its operation or not. Below is simplified explanation of asynchronous code in C# and why it might be bad to return `void` from the `async` method.

#### A bit about asynchronousy

The way how we can describe an asynchronous operations is that the operation is not blocking which means that you can tell that you want to begin the operation and continue doing other stuff not waiting the operation to finish its work. But this is not very useful to just start the operation (sometimes it might be useful), you usually want to do something when the operation is completed, failed etc. So in .NET the async operation returns `Task` or `Task<T>` which is the abstraction over the operation which might be completed or might be still in progress. Then you can attach your own code to be executed when a `task` is completed.

#### What happens under the hood when you await an operation

*Keep in mind that this description is **too** simplified than what is actually happening.*

So when you do something like this:

```
 public async Task IFYT_Playlist () {
    await this.getPlaylistItemsAsync();
    ... Do some other stuff when the `getPlaylistItemsAsync` has been completed
 }
```

The `IFYT_Playlist` method attaches the code which is below `await this.getPlaylistItemsAsync();` to the task which is returned by the method and **return immediately**. Again this is not what's actually happening, but can get you a basic idea:

```
public async Task IFYT_Playlist () {
    Task resTask = this.getPlaylistItemsAsync();
    return resTask.ContinueWith(t => ...Do some other stuff when the `getPlaylistItemsAsync` has been completed);
 }
```

So that as it turned out async operation should return `Task` so that the caller will be able to attach a continuation to it (with `ContinueWith`) method. Do you see the problem now? If your return type is `void`, the caller won't be able to attach the code which should be executed when the operation has been completed. So, if `getPlaylistItemsAsync`'s returns type is `void`, you can't await `this.getPlaylistItemsAsync()`, because it's impossible to call `ContinueWith` on nothing (`void`). Therefore you can't even have `await` with method that returns `void`.

```
 public async Task IFYT_Playlist () {
    await this.getPlaylistItemsAsync(); // doesn't compile
 }
```

Therefore your `update` method should return `Task` or `Task<T>` for any suitable `T` in your case rather than nothing (`void`).

Comment: thanks so much! 
so if I understand you correctly if I do this:

Task mytask = await methodThatReturnsTask();
Console.Writeline("Foo");

it should start doing whatever is in the method and then return to the caller (in this case write something to the console)
 In my example that does not happen?

Comment: What you described is more similar to synchronous execution, like you call the method, wait for it to finish, and then continue doing whatever is below the call. In our case as soon as your method encounters the `await` keyword, it will call the method to the right of `await` (`methodThatReturnsTask `), then **wait** for the method to return **Task** (which usually is in progress), then attaches continuation to the task (`Console.WriteLine("Foo")`) and then returns back to the caller. Right after your `task` has been completed, the Console.WriteLine("Foo") will be executed.

Comment: Note the differences between *waiting for the operation/method to complete* and *waiting for the method to return `Task`*. These are very different, in the first case if your method performs some time-consuming task you will be wait for it and you won't be able to do anything else. In the second case, however, you're waiting olny for task to be created and returned which should be fast operation.

Comment: Therefore, if your method `methodThatReturnsTask ` is performing some time-consuming operation before returning the task, your code will be actually blocked until the `methodThatReturnsTask` returns task.